# TCCR1A and TCCR2A on Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo, library, timers, arduino-micro

I'm trying to use the [TTS library for Arduino](https://github.com/jscrane/TTS) on an Arduino Micro board, which is based on the Leonardo. When I try to compile my sketch I get some errors;

```
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp: In function 'void soundOff()':
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:355: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:355: error: 'COM2B1' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp: In function 'void soundOn()':
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:382: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:382: error: 'COM2B1' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:382: error: 'WGM20' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:383: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:383: error: 'CS20' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:383: error: 'WGM22' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:384: error: 'OCR2B' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:385: error: 'TCNT2' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp: In function 'void sound(byte)':
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:424: error: 'OCR2B' was not declared in this scope
/libraries/TTS/TTS.cpp:425: error: 'TCNT2' was not declared in this scope
```

Googling revealed that the Leonardo uses different timers. And other things I don't understand! But I couldn't piece together an answer beyond that.

What are the correct constants to use for Leonardo boards, and is there a way I can update the library to work across both?

Comment: The hilarious part is that the Arduino libraries provide MCU-independent ways to do all that and this code completely ignores all of them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Great news! Do you have a link on how to use that feature of the library, or an example please?

Comment: This "library" is written specifically for the ATMega328 (not the ATmega32u4 inside the Leonardo).  You should be able to port it. Not hard, but not also a task for a beginner.

Comment: Eh. I just noticed that it uses parameters not controlled by the basic libraries. You'd need to find a more fully-featured PWM library for it. But barring that conditional compilation would be the way to go.

Comment: Do you _have to_ use a Micro? Your code will probably work on a Uno (or some other ATmega328 based board). To check, select Uno under the `Tools->Board` menu and then try to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the library in [the OP's link](https://github.com/jscrane/TTS) has been updated to support the Leonardo, so this problem should now be solved.

Comment: This is the Leonardo patch in case its useful to anyone https://github.com/jscrane/TTS/pull/6/commits/d84cbd2eb39e513e62b4f33a55ccfad412f5aec8